# Replace Jackson with kotlinx.serialization in Javalin framework

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, javalin

I'm trying to replace the default [Javalin](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin) JSON serializer Jackson by Kotlinx.serialization.

The documentation show how to do it [with GSON serializer](https://javalin.io/documentation#using-gson).
Unfortunately kotlinx serializer has a different function signature and I can't figure out how to pass arguments through.

Serialization is OK but deserialization with decodeFromString function require to be passed a type given by the mapping function as `targetClass`.

I'm stuck here:

```kotlin
val kotlinx = Json { coerceInputValues = true }
    
JavalinJson.toJsonMapper = object : ToJsonMapper {
    override fun map(obj: Any): String = kotlinx.encodeToString(obj)
}
    
JavalinJson.fromJsonMapper = object : FromJsonMapper {
    override fun <T> map(json: String, targetClass: Class<T>): T = kotlinx.decodeFromString(json)
}
```

But I get: `Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.`

I also tried:

```kotlin
JavalinJson.fromJsonMapper = object : FromJsonMapper {
    override inline fun <reified T> map(json: String, targetClass: Class<T>): T = kotlinx.decodeFromString(json)
}
```

But I get a warning: `Override by an inline function` and an error: `Override by a function with reified type parameter`.

I'm new to `kotlin` and I'm struggling understanding what's wrong with this override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```kotlin
JavalinJson.toJsonMapper = object : ToJsonMapper {
    override fun map(obj: Any): String {
        val serializer = serializer(obj.javaClass)
        return kotlinx.encodeToString(serializer, obj)
    }
}

JavalinJson.fromJsonMapper = object : FromJsonMapper {
    override fun <T> map(json: String, targetClass: Class<T>): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val deserializer = serializer(targetClass) as KSerializer<T>
        return kotlinx.decodeFromString(deserializer, json)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks better than before. I'm always getting some errors though. `Serializer for class 'Any' is not found`. The problem is that `serializer(targetClass)` returns a `KSerializer<Any>` and not a `KSerializer<T>`.

Comment: I tried `val deserializer: KSerializer<T> = serializer<T>()` that seems more appropriate but I'm having the `reified` issue again..

Comment: Seems, this error is related to `toJsonMapper`. Edited answer, added this one too.

Comment: Now I get this error: `Serializer for class 'GenericResponse' is not found. Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly` which is better because `GenericResponse` is my serialized data class. The strange thing is that this class is already tagged as `Serializable`.

Comment: Are you sure you added Kotlin Serialization compiler plugin to your project?

Comment: yes I followed the setup procedure of kotlinx README.md and add `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.10"` to plugins and `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0")` to dependencies

Comment: Are you sure you are using `kotlinx.serialization.Serializable`, not `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: Can't reproduce in JVM... What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222814/discussion-between-freezystem-and--).